# PHP Get value from JSON

Tags: php, json

Let's say I have this JSON:

```
{
  "achievement": [
    {
      "title": "Ready for Work",
      "description": "Sign up and get validated",
      "xp": 50,
      "difficulty": 1,
      "level_req": 1
    },
    {
      "title": "All Around Submitter",
      "description": "Get one piece of textual content approved in all five areas.",
      "xp": 500,
      "difficulty": 2,
      "level_req": 1
    }
}
```

and I am trying this thru PHP:

```
$string = file_get_contents("achievements.json");
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);

$getit = $json_a->achievement['title'][1];
```

I'm trying to get the first "id" of the achievement.. which would be `READY FOR WORK`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: just to mention, there's a missing `]` before the last `}`, cause the one you posted isn't valid until that missing square bracket is added.

Comment: Your json is not valid  and would always return error

Comment: I know it's not valid. It's longer so I just gave a short snippet. All is well.

Comment: A related reference question: [How to extract and access data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29308898/367456)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you set the second parameter of `json_decode` to `true`, it will return an array.

```
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);
```

returns an array.

```
$getit = $json_a['achievement'][1]['title'];
```

Comment: And change the index from 1 to zero to get the Ready for Work item. After all, arrays in PHP are are zero based indexed.

Comment: Ah, right, I am so silly to be like.. what. Thanks. So.. the IDs start from 0.

Comment: @weka Yes, `1` means second element of `$json_a['achievement']`.