# How to extract and access data from JSON with PHP?

Tags: php, json

> This is intended to be a general reference question and answer covering many of the never-ending *"How do I access data in my JSON?"* questions. It is here to handle the broad basics of decoding JSON in PHP and accessing the results.

I have the JSON:

```
{
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "toppings": [
        { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
        { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
        { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
    ]
}
```

How do I decode this in PHP and access the resulting data?

Comment: Related: [Able to see a variable in print_r()'s output, but not sure how to access it in code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6322084/367456), interactive JSON exploration in context of PHP is possible here: http://array.include-once.org/

Comment: Please can I know that why this question not consider as a duplicate question even 9 or less users marked as a duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php? M

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson I'll try to explain, even though your username makes me doubt you'll get it ;). This question is asked, and its answers are written, in a "canonical" way. As such, it's a better recipient for duplicate target than the other questions.

Answer (score 599):

#### *Intro*

First off you have a string. JSON is not an array, an object, or a data structure. [JSON](http://json.org/) is a text-based serialization format - so a fancy string, but still just a string. Decode it in PHP by using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode).

```
 $data = json_decode($json);
```

Therein you might find:

- scalars: [strings](http://php.net/string), [ints](http://php.net/int), [floats](http://php.net/float), and [bools](http://php.net/bool)
- [nulls](http://php.net/null) (a special type of its own)
- compound types: [objects](http://php.net/object) and [arrays](http://php.net/array).

These are the things that can be encoded in JSON. Or more accurately, these are PHP's versions of the things that can be encoded in JSON.

There's nothing special about them. They are not "JSON objects" or "JSON arrays." You've decoded the JSON - you now have [basic everyday PHP types](http://php.net/types).

Objects will be instances of [stdClass](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php), a built-in class which is just a [generic thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php) that's not important here.

---

#### *Accessing object properties*

You access the [properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) of one of these objects the same way you would for the public non-static properties of any other object, e.g. `$object->property`.

```
$json = '
{
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake"
}';

$yummy = json_decode($json);

echo $yummy->type; //donut
```

---

#### *Accessing array elements*

You access the elements of one of these arrays the same way you would for any other array, e.g. [`$array[0]`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing).

```
$json = '
[
    "Glazed",
    "Chocolate with Sprinkles",
    "Maple"
]';

$toppings = json_decode($json);

echo $toppings[1]; //Chocolate with Sprinkles
```

Iterate over it with [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

```
foreach ($toppings as $topping) {
    echo $topping, "\n";
}
```

> Glazed 
>   Chocolate with Sprinkles 
>   Maple

Or mess about with any of the [bazillion built-in array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

---

#### *Accessing nested items*

The properties of objects and the elements of arrays might be more objects and/or arrays - you can simply continue to access their properties and members as usual, e.g. `$object->array[0]->etc`.

```
$json = '
{
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "toppings": [
        { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
        { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
        { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
    ]
}';

$yummy = json_decode($json);

echo $yummy->toppings[2]->id; //5004
```

---

#### *Passing `true` as the second argument to [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode)*

When you do this, instead of objects you'll get associative arrays - arrays with strings for keys. Again you access the elements thereof as usual, e.g. `$array['key']`.

```
$json = '
{
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "toppings": [
        { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
        { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
        { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
    ]
}';

$yummy = json_decode($json, true);

echo $yummy['toppings'][2]['type']; //Maple
```

---

#### *Accessing associative array items*

When decoding a JSON *object* to an associative PHP array, you can iterate both keys and values using the [`foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)`](https://www.php.net/manual/control-structures.foreach.php) syntax, eg

```php
$json = '
{
    "foo": "foo value",
    "bar": "bar value",
    "baz": "baz value"
}';

$assoc = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($assoc as $key => $value) {
    echo "The value of key '$key' is '$value'", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Prints

> The value of key 'foo' is 'foo value'
>   The value of key 'bar' is 'bar value'
>   The value of key 'baz' is 'baz value'

---

#### *Don't know how the data is structured*

Read the documentation for whatever it is you're getting the JSON from.

Look at the JSON - where you see curly brackets `{}` expect an object, where you see square brackets `[]` expect an array.

Hit the decoded data with a [`print_r()`](http://php.net/print_r):

```
$json = '
{
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "toppings": [
        { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
        { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
        { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
    ]
}';

$yummy = json_decode($json);

print_r($yummy);
```

and check the output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [type] => donut
    [name] => Cake
    [toppings] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 5002
                    [type] => Glazed
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 5006
                    [type] => Chocolate with Sprinkles
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 5004
                    [type] => Maple
                )

        )

)
```

It'll tell you where you have objects, where you have arrays, along with the names and values of their members.

If you can only get so far into it before you get lost - go that far and hit *that* with `print_r()`:

```
print_r($yummy->toppings[0]);
```

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 5002
    [type] => Glazed
)
```

Take a look at it in [this handy interactive JSON explorer](http://array.include-once.org/).

Break the problem down into pieces that are easier to wrap your head around.

---

#### *`json_decode()` returns `null`*

This happens because either:

1. The JSON consists entirely of just that, `null`.
2. The JSON is invalid - check the result of [`json_last_error_msg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) or put it through something like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).
3. It contains elements nested more than 512 levels deep. This default max depth can be overridden by passing an integer as the third argument to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode).

If you need to change the max depth you're probably solving the wrong problem. Find out why you're getting such deeply nested data (e.g. the service you're querying that's generating the JSON has a bug) and get that to not happen.

---

#### *Object property name contains a special character*

Sometimes you'll have an object property name that contains something like a hyphen `-` or at sign `@` which can't be used in a literal identifier. Instead you can use a string literal within curly braces to address it.

```
$json = '{"@attributes":{"answer":42}}';
$thing = json_decode($json);

echo $thing->{'@attributes'}->answer; //42
```

If you have an integer as property see: [How to access object properties with names like integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333016/how-to-access-object-properties-with-names-like-integers) as reference.

---

#### *Someone put JSON in your JSON*

It's ridiculous but it happens - there's JSON encoded as a string within your JSON. Decode, access the string as usual, decode *that*, and eventually get to what you need.

```
$json = '
{
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "toppings": "[{ \"type\": \"Glazed\" }, { \"type\": \"Maple\" }]"
}';

$yummy = json_decode($json);
$toppings = json_decode($yummy->toppings);

echo $toppings[0]->type; //Glazed
```

---

#### *Data doesn't fit in memory*

If your JSON is too large for `json_decode()` to handle at once things start to get tricky. See:

- [Processing large JSON files in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4049428/3942918)
- [How to properly iterate through a big json file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26393235/3942918)

---

#### *How to sort it*

See: [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17364127/3942918).

Comment: just stumbled at this answer and found that the link to http://array.include-once.org/ is broken.

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
$jsonData = '{
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "toppings": [
        { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
        { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
        { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
    ]
}';

// Decode the JSON
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);

// Access the data
$type = $data['type'];
$name = $data['name'];
$toppings = $data['toppings'];

// Access individual topping details
$firstTopping = $toppings[0];
$firstToppingId = $firstTopping['id'];
$firstToppingType = $firstTopping['type'];

// Print the data
echo "Type: $type\n";
echo "Name: $name\n";
echo "First Topping ID: $firstToppingId\n";
echo "First Topping Type: $firstToppingType\n";
?>
```

In this example, json_decode() is used to decode the JSON data into a PHP associative array. You can then access the individual elements of the array as you would with any PHP array.